# Parse Log In Customisation - Use of undeclared identifier 'Label'

Tags: parse-platform

I'm trying to customise the Parse `logInViewController` and it produces errors about undeclared labels and expecting identifier or '('.

Errors:

- Parse issue: Expected identifier or '('
- Semantic issue: Use of undeclared identifier 'label'
- Semantic issue: Use of undeclared identifier 'label'

  `#import "MyLogInViewController.h" 
   @implementation MyLogInViewController - (void) viewDidLoad 
   { 
     [super viewDidLoad]; 
     self.view.backgroundColor = [UIColor colorWithPatternImage: [UIImage imageNamed:@"myBackgroundImage.png"]]; 
      struct label.text = @"My Logo"; 
      [label sizeToFit]; 
      self.logInView.logo = label; // logo can be any UIView 
   } 
   @end`

Comment: It may help if your posted some code.

Comment: #import "MyLogInViewController.h"

(at sign)implementation MyLogInViewController

- (void) viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];
    self.view.backgroundColor = [UIColor colorWithPatternImage:
        [UIImage imageNamed:@"myBackgroundImage.png"]];
    struct label.text = @"My Logo";
    [label sizeToFit];
    self.logInView.logo = label; // logo can be any UIView
}
(at sign)end